# Toolbar and top of it Contextual actionbar android

Tags: android

i run in to issue!

I want my app look just like  here [example tutorial](http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html)

so i created everything by that tutorial but only used appcompatActivity. and everything else i left the same but outcome was that there was only toolbar and no actionbar;/.

a tried to find  answer on my self . And first  found this:
http://solvedstack.com/questions/toolbar-and-contextual-actionbar-with-appcompat-v7

but that wasn't exactly thing what i was looking for . Never then less it didnt work. So i looked for other tutorials but could find the right one because mostly they where deprecated or teaches how to use toolbar instead of action bar. But i want both  of them.

maybe some tip on how to fix it ?

Comment: Why would you want to use `ActionBar` and `Toolbar` that makes no sense. You use one or the other not both

Comment: well the idea was to create something like this http://prntscr.com/88qvkj
if it's done differently i would appreciate guidance :D

Comment: so just use a toolbar with a top margin...

Comment: and the upper thing is just image with text?